# How to update Typography text on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI Typography, the text (ABC) of which needs to be updated to (XYZ) on button click. Below is the code for Typography

```
function handleDrawerOpen() {
setOpen(true);
//update ABC to XYZ
}

function handleDrawerClose() {
setOpen(false);
}

return (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <AppBar
    position="fixed"
    className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
      [classes.appBarShift]: open,
    })}
  >
    <Toolbar>
      <IconButton
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="open drawer"
        onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
        edge="start"
        className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
          [classes.hide]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Typography className={classes.GStyle} variant="h6" noWrap>
          {classes.drawerOpen ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'}
        </Typography>
      </IconButton>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <Drawer
    variant="permanent"
    className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
      [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
      [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
    })}
    classes={{
      paper: clsx({
        [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
        [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
      }),
    }}
    open={open}
  >
    <div className={classes.toolbar}>
      <IconButton className={classes.icon} onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
      </IconButton>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple conditional and a flag stored in your state (which it looks like you already have in your `open` flag for the drawer):

```
 <Typography className = {classes.GStyle} variant="h6" noWrap>
        {open ? 'XYZ' : 'ABC' }
  </Typography>
```

You may wish to read up on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in React. You'll find yourself needing to accomplish similar things quite often in a typical React application, and there are a lot of different methods of implementation that will be useful to know.

Comment: `const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);` this is how its there but i am not able to get the `open` value, so on click event text is not updating? What's wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to get it, is there an error? There should be no issue simply inserting it into your JSX. Please post the full component so I can see how you're implementing your click handler.

Comment: I have update my Post with full code, please see..Thanks

Comment: Well for one thing, your ```Drawer``` is missing a closing tag.  If that's the complete code you're working with it won't compile, so this is not the full code. But from what I can see, assuming you don't have any syntax errors simply replacing ```{classes.drawerOpen ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'}``` with ```{open ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'}``` will work if everything you've said is accurate, but no one can know without the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**: use state.

example:

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'ABC',
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({text: 'XYZ'});
  }
  
  render(){
    const { text } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here</button>
        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It would probably be useful to allow it to toggle in your example. Nice job